# reshape dataframe by splitting characters in a column in to separate rows

Tags: r, reshape

How can i reshape my data.frame by splitting the gene names and Enseble_Id into  separate columns

```
    df1<-
         ID     chrom loc.start   loc.end  num.mark  seg.mean  Genes          Gene.N        Ensemble_ID
        88410     1   3010000    173490000   8430    0.0039    Sntg1,Rrs1    SNT,ELF   ENSMUSG00000025909,ENSMUSG00000061024,
        88410     1   173510000  173590000   5      -1.77380  Ifi203,Mndal   REK,MNDAL   ENSMUSG00000049598,ENSMUSG00000026104  


   expected output

     Gene.N   Genes   Ensemble_ID         ID      chrom   loc.start  loc.end    num.mark  seg.mean   
       SNT    Sntg1   ENSMUSG00000025909  88410    1     3010000    173490000    8430     0.0039 
       ELF    Rrs1    ENSMUSG00000061024  88410    1     3010000    173490000    8430     0.0039 
       REK    Ifi203  ENSMUSG00000049598  88410    1     173510000  173590000     5      -1.77380 
       MNDAL  Mndal   ENSMUSG00000026104  88410    1     173510000  173590000     5      -1.77380
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, c("Genes", "Gene.N", "Ensemble_ID"), ",", "long")
#       ID chrom loc.start   loc.end num.mark seg.mean  Genes Gene.N        Ensemble_ID
# 1: 88410     1   3010000 173490000     8430   0.0039  Sntg1    SNT ENSMUSG00000025909
# 2: 88410     1   3010000 173490000     8430   0.0039   Rrs1    ELF ENSMUSG00000061024
# 3: 88410     1 173510000 173590000        5  -1.7738 Ifi203    REK ENSMUSG00000049598
# 4: 88410     1 173510000 173590000        5  -1.7738  Mndal  MNDAL ENSMUSG00000026104
```